# How to get localized message or error code in QBEntityCallbackImpl

Tags: android, quickblox

QBEntityCallbackImpl has 2 methods

```
public void onSuccess(ArrayList<QBDialog> dialogs, Bundle args)
```

and

```
public void onError(List<String> errors)
```

And looks like there is no way to get errorCode such as 401, or so on from QBEntityCallbackImpl ? Beacause I want to show normal message to my users with translation to their language.

And in android logs - QBSDK is logging this codes...

Answer (score 0):

Such a way will be added in a new Android WebRTC SDK which is to be released on August 27-28.